# ASP.net Validation no fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have no idea why my validation doesn't work as when I click on the Create button the page just refresh even my field doesn't enter any value. But when I key in value at username field the REgularValidator will appear even.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="createmember.aspx.cs" Inherits="member" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#MainContent_username").change(function () {
                    var uname = $("#MainContent_username");
                    var msgbox = $("#status");
                    if (uname.val().length < 6) {
                        msgbox.html('<font color="#cc0000">User Name must be more than 5 characters</font>');
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "createmember.aspx/DoesUserExist",
                            data: "{'username': '" + uname.val() + "'}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (msg) {
                                if (msg.d == false) {
                                    msgbox.html('<font color="Green">User Name Available </font>');
                                }
                                else {
                                    msgbox.html('<font color="Red">User Name Exist</font>');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
        <h2>
            Create Member</h2>

        <fieldset>
            <div id="createform">
                <div class="formlabel">
                    Login Name :</div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="username" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <span id="usernameempty"></span>
                <span id="status"></span>
                <br />
                <div class="formlabel">
                    Password :</div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <div class="formlabel">
                    First Name :</div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="firstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <div class="formlabel">
                    Last Name :</div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="lastname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <br />
                <div class="formlabel">
                    Email :</div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <div class="formlabel">
                    User Role :</div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="role" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Admin</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Staff</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Driver</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Manager</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Super Admin</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="submit_Click" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <div style="clear: both;" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </asp:Content>
```

My backend code.

```
 static string connectionString;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=db;UID=root;PASSWORD=password;";
}
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string usertypevalue = role.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string firstnamevalue = firstname.Text;
    string lastnamevalue = lastname.Text;
    string usernamevalue = username.Text;
    string passwordvalue = password.Text;
    if (!DoesUserExist(usernamevalue))
    {
        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "Insert into user (UserTypeID, FirstName, LastName, LoginName, LoginPassword, DateTimeCreated, LastLoginDate) values ('"
            + usertypevalue + "','" + firstnamevalue + "','" + lastnamevalue + "','" + usernamevalue + "','" + passwordvalue + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')";
        try
        {
            //connect.Open();
           // command.Connection = connect;
            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            msg.Text = "Member account created successfully";
            msg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        catch
        {
            msg.Text = "Error Occured, Please try again!";
            msg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool DoesUserExist(string username)
{
    bool exist = false;
    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {

        connect.Open();
        string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM User WHERE LoginName = '" + username + "'";
        //Create Mysql Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);

        //ExecuteScalar will return one value
        int Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");
        if (Count > 0)
        {
            exist = true;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connect.Close();
    }
    return exist;
}
```

Comment: what do u need to do by RegularExpressionValidator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation succeeds if the input control is empty. If a value is required for the associated input control, use a RequiredFieldValidator control in addition to the RegularExpressionValidator control.

[RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

it seems ValidationGroup Problem... if you need to validate any control on button click the the control,the validator and the button should be at same Group so if you use the following for your textbox, validator and for button , I hope it solves your problem

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="username" ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="username" ValidationGroup="group1" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
                SetFocusOnError="True">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
............
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group1" Text="Create" OnClick="submit_Click" />
```